# How to make commerce coinbase webhook to connect to laravel application

Tags: laravel, coinbase-api

I am building a laravel application that will use commerce coinbase to accept payments. I have implemented all the necessary things. I have added the webhook route to the exceptions in VerifyCsrfToken.

On Coinbase send test page, if I pass any website design with laravel example laracast, I will get the "Failed to establish a connection" error message. However, if I pass other website, it will establish connection. Below is the picture of the error.

[image]

Comment: If you are testing on your localhost, you're most likely to encounter this error. Download ngrok and tunnel to your localhost. Then use the https generated by ngrok as your webhhook url.

Comment: in development it works, but when i use AWS URL it is giving same error. How do i resolve it.